# Mixing Spark Structured Streaming API and DStream to write to Kafka

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I've recently noticed I have a confusion regarding Spark Streaming (I'm currently learning Spark).

I am reading data from a Kafka topic like this:

```
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      streamingContext,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )
```

Which creates a DStream.

In order to work with event-time (and not processing-time) I did this:

```
outputStream
      .foreachRDD(rdd => {
          rdd.toDF().withWatermark("timestamp", "60 seconds")
            .groupBy(
              window($"timestamp", "60 seconds", "10 seconds")
            )
            .sum("meterIncrement")
            .toJSON
            .toDF("value")
            .writeStream
            .format("kafka")
            .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
            .option("topic", "taxi-dollar-accurate")
            .start()
        )
      })
```

And I get the error

> 'writeStream' can be called only on streaming Dataset/DataFrame

Which surprised me, because the source of the DF is a DStream. Anyway, I managed to solve this by changing .writeStream to .write and .start() to .save().

But I got the feeling that I lost the streaming power on that foreach somehow. Clearly that's why I am writing this question. Is this a correct approach? I've seen other scripts that use

```
val df = spark
  .readStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "topic1")
  .load()
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

But I don't know how different is this from just calling foreach on the DStream and then transforming each RDD to DF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don't know how different is this from just calling foreach on the DStream and then transforming each RDD to DF.

When you are calling:

```scala
outputStream
      .foreachRDD(rdd => {
          rdd.toDF()
            .[...]
            .toJSON
            .toDF("value")
            .writeStream
            .format("kafka")
```

your variable `rdd` (or the Dataframe) became a *single* RDD which is not a stream anymore. Hence, the `rdd.toDF.[...].writeStream` will not work anymore.

#### Continue with RDD

If you choose to use the DSream approach, you can send those *single* RDDs calling the KafkaProducer API.

An example:

```scala
dstream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
  rdd.foreachPartition { partitionOfRecords =>
    val producer = new KafkaProducer[String, String](kafkaParameters)
    partitionOfRecords.foreach { message =>
      producer.send(message)
    }
    producer.close()
  }
}
```

**However, this is not the recommended approach as you are creating and closing a KafkaProducer in each batch interval on each executor.** But this should give you a basic understanding on how to write data to Kafka using the DirectStream API.

To further optimize sending your data to Kafka you can follow the guidance given [here](https://allegro.tech/2015/08/spark-kafka-integration.html).

#### Continue with Dataframe

However, you could also transform your RDD into a Dataframe, but then making sure to call the batch-oriented API to write data into Kafka:

```
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
  .option("topic", "topic1")
  .save()
```

For all the details on how to write a batch Dataframe into Kafka is geven in the [Spark Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-the-output-of-batch-queries-to-kafka)

#### Note

Still, and most importantly, I highly recommend to **not** mix up RDD and Structured API for such a case and rather stick to the one or the other.